# FileSystemWatcher does not work in Linux, is there any way to get around this issue?

Tags: c#, centos, .net-5

Apparently (according to dotnet github) `FileSystemWatcher` is not compatible with Linux (well then I have no idea how exactly they claim .Net as cross platform!).

Anyway, is there any other method (lower level approach) to implement a file watcher in C# which would be compatible with any Linux environment?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57024640/why-filesystemwatcher-doesnt-work-in-linux-container-watching-windows-volume) is not helpful. I Have already come across that. The solution in this question does not provide file information when a change event is raised.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why FileSystemWatcher doesn't work in Linux container watching Windows volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57024640/why-filesystemwatcher-doesnt-work-in-linux-container-watching-windows-volume) and [Is there an equivalent to the .Net FileSystemWatcher in the Linux world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324258/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-net-filesystemwatcher-in-the-linux-world)

Comment: What worked for me, was to change the all backslashes (used in Microsoft file system paths) into forwardslashes (used in Linux file system paths)