# How to use FileSystemWatcher on Linux with .NET 5.0+

Tags: c#, .net, cross-platform, .net-5, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to watch for changes in a specified directory using the FileSystemWatcher class. Based heavily off of the example on the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0#examples) which works fine on my windows machine. The problem though, I'm targeting Ubtuntu 18.04 lts and greater for running this. The *watcher* apparently sets up just fine (code executes and console/logging messages are printed out) but none of the file system events are ever triggered, ie: Change/Create/Delete/Rename/etc nothing triggers those.

Are there any undocumented or "hidden" setup details needed to work with Linux, or is this not supported altogether and even though it's in .NET 5 shouldn't be used for Linux/Mac/Unix builds? I can't find any definitive docs on non-Windows usage, but thought that .NET 5 was meant to work "portably."
Any tips/details would be appreciated as I'm sure others have come across this as well, or are at least likely to.

Current code that works with Windows build but not Linux:

```
public void WatchFolder()
{
    string directoryPath = _configuration["FolderLocation"];

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(directoryPath))
        throw new Exception("Folder location was not set.");

    try
    {
        // setup file system watcher
        using var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(directoryPath);
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                         | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                         | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                         | NotifyFilters.FileName
                         | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                         | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                         | NotifyFilters.Security
                         | NotifyFilters.Size;

        // add handler methods
        watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        watcher.Created += OnCreated;
        watcher.Deleted += OnDeleted;
        watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;
        watcher.Error += OnError;

        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // wait for next key to kill execution
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Couldn't watch folder: {directoryPath}\nBecause: {ex}");
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Attempting to use the answer in this related SO quetion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57025115/8645002 did not fix the issue. The delegate still doesn't trigger when running the built exe in a Linux environment.

note: building for Linux x64 single file self-contained exe.

Comment: Try setting `watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;`. But test this: [Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.physical/)

Comment: What if I want  to watch sub directories though, I would then need to make a new watcher for every sub dir?

Comment: The test is to verify whether the problem still exists, the NuGet package is the replacement in case the tests gives the results expected.

Comment: Ok, so it made no difference when doing that. @Jimi What NuGet package do I want to use now? Not sure I understand you last comment though.

Comment: The one linked in the first comment?

Comment: Ah, so I do have that package installed and included. I even tried passing the watcher into a PhysicalFileWatcher with polling enabled. What else should be tried?

Comment: When you call `[PhysicalFileProvider].Watch("*")`, it returns an [IChangeToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.ichangetoken) (store it as a Field), then you call [IChangeToken.RegisterChangeCallback()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.ichangetoken.registerchangecallback) (it's an Action delegate, so register a `void` method - don't use a Lambda). The callback notifies a `State` (as an object) when a state in the watched path changes.

Comment: What does one do when that doesn't work? I'm building a self-contained Linux exe which doesn't trigger the delegate when run in WSL2 but works fine in debug for Windows.